# Evaluating string cells in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, matrix

I have,

```
labels = {'A' , 'B' , 'C'};

results =
           A
           A
           C
           .
           .
           B
```

`result` is a `1000*1` *char*,

I want compare the the `labels` with `results` and get a *logical* array.

I finally found that,

```
n = cellstr(results);
m = 'A';
strcmp(n,m)
```

works, but I want to do it in a loop, so I cant have `m = 'A';`, it should be `m = labels(1);`, which won't work.

Comment: why don't you use `ismember` function?

Comment: @NKN, I tried but I couldn't figure it out. Can you give an example with the above arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
n = cellstr(results);

for k=1:3
  m = labels(k);
  strcmp(n,m);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) like this (`v` is like `cellstr(result)` in your case):

```
>> labels = {'A' , 'B' , 'C'};
>> v = cellstr(char(randi(15,20,1)+64)).' %' uni. random sample of letters from A to O

v = 

  Columns 1 through 10

    'M'    'D'    'I'    'J'    'A'    'J'    'F'    'A'    'H'    'C'

  Columns 11 through 20

    'B'    'D'    'C'    'C'    'A'    'J'    'E'    'I'    'K'    'H'

>> [lia,locb] = ismember(v,labels)

lia =

  Columns 1 through 12

     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0

  Columns 13 through 20

     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0


locb =

  Columns 1 through 12

     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     3     2     0

  Columns 13 through 20

     3     3     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

This might help clarify the outputs:

```
>> v(lia)

ans = 

    'A'    'A'    'C'    'B'    'C'    'C'    'A'

>> labels(locb(lia))

ans = 

    'A'    'A'    'C'    'B'    'C'    'C'    'A'
```

In other works, `find(lia)` are the indexes in `v` of the characters that also exist in `labels`, and `locb(lia)` gives the index into `labels` for those elements.